# jquery modal dialog button div not aligning right - css makes it occupy total row

Tags: jquery, css, modal-dialog

I'm new to stylesheet and need help with below. My JSP code uses modal dialog example similar to demo from https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form

I am using the same CSS and JS, jquery library from this website.

I have a requirement where within a DIV I would have to have a button on the rightside to 'Add'(leftdiv) and pagination on the right(rightdiv).

The button would open a modal dialog from the opensource above and uses its CSS. The rightside alignment uses my CSS and works fine, however the modal button which is supposed to align left is towards the right.

When I inspect in chrome the parent div shows 2 DIV's in 2 different rows. The first row contains the left div and the 2nd the rightDiv.

```
<div>
  <div class="LeftAlign">
    <button id="create-user">Add</button>
  </div>
  <div class="RightAlign">Pagination</div>
</div>
```

When I inspect button holds this `class = "ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget"`. How should I interpret this in the code.

How can I change my CSS to make the button moveleft and pagination aligned right in a single row. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give display:flex; style to your parent div e.g:-

```
.first {display:flex;}
.RightAlign { margin-left: auto;}
```

So HTML would be:-

```
<div class="first">
  <div class="LeftAlign">
    <button id="create-user">Add</button>
  </div>
  <div class="RightAlign">Pagination</div>
</div>
```

Comment: used this <div style="display:flex"><div class="LeftAlign">
<button id="create-user">Add</button>
</div>
<div class="RightAlign">Pagination</div>
</div>

Comment: Now the leftalign is working and the right pagination is moved next to the left div button. I mean the right is no more aligned to right,